# Why don't virtual machines have operating systems?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, jvm

In the context of programing languages, if compiled code runs on some sort of virtual machine why does the virtual machine not need an operating system? For example with Java, a program written in Java runs in the JVM but (as far as I'm aware) the JVM does not have an OS. I know operating systems are necessary because they manage resources (e.g.which process gets a turn with the CPU) so how can the JVM not need one? My understanding of a virtual machine is that it is its own processor with it's own architecture and instructions, but can the term "virtual machine" be though of as coming with its own operating system?

Comment: What function would this OS provide?

Comment: @ikegami scheduling for which thread gets time in CPU, memory management, basically anything a normal OS would do. I don't get your point?

Comment: But it's doing all that already without the OS. So again, what function would this OS provide?

Comment: @ikegami I see what you're saying. doesn't that mean that JVM IS an operating system since you just said "it's doing all that"

Comment: Nope, the JVM doesn't know anything about any of those. "It", in this case, is the Java libraries.

Comment: Something like Tomcat running on top of JVM can be called an operating system.

Comment: I seriously think this question should have gotten better explained answers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the "eye" can tell, the virtual machine is its own operating system. It just has no physical hardware to account for.

The (physical/real) CPU executes the JVM - this is platform dependant, the JVM then executes the Java code - this is platform independant.

So the JVM does actually need an operating system. There is a different between being independant of an OS and not needed one. Independant in this case means that to Java, it doesn't matter on which OS you run it. As long as the JVM is present, it will work fine. The JVM has to make sure that your Java code gets executed correctly by the underlying Operating System.

Comment: A rather myopic eye!  There are some critical things that an OS does / needs to do that are not provided by a JVM; e.g. see Thorbjorn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the JVM does not need an operating system.

The JVM is specified on its own, separate from a specific operating system.  It is useful without having to specify an operating system, and, as pointed out elsewhere, there is such a thing as a JVM without what we usually think of as an operating system.

Java was originally developed, in fact, for use in things like kitchen appliances -- no file system, no mouse or keyboard, maybe a keypad and some 7-digit display, that's it.

So when a Java program needs to run on a machine that IS complex enough to need an operating system, then Java interacts with whatever operating system is there -- Windows, Mac OS, Unix, etc. -- and parts of its core classes abstract many of the normal operating system operations to the extent that a single Java program can run on any of these without changes.  Certainly there are difficulties with this -- it is a difficult thing to do -- but Java does this more broadly and better than anything else I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM known to most Java programmers - the Oracle JVM - expects to run under an existing operating system (Linux, Windows, Solaris etc), but JVM's exist that expects to run on the bare metal.  See http://jnode.org for such a JVM.

Unfortunately the Oracle JVM lacks some necessary facilities to be able to build the facilites provided by the operating system into the JVM itself.  For instance you cannot limit the amount of memory or cpu used by a single thread, and you cannot forcibly kill a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Real virtual machines need operating systems.  But Java's so-called virtual machine is not a virtual machine.  It implements an idealized instruction set within the context of an operating system, usually within a user-mode process.  Before Java mis-used that term, we used to call these things pseudo-code interpreters, and some very powerful systems were built with them.

Answer (score -2):

Java is just an interpreter of its own code. Not a VM in a full sence